# Linq retrieve a summary list in a query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a query

```
var query =
    from p in db.Person
    join l in db.PersonLanguage on p.personId equals l.personId
    select new (p, **as a single field I want a list of languages**)
```

Im wondering if this is possible, or do I need to iterate over the result and do seperate queries so that I can get the list. The list im after would be ideally seperated by spaces but any seperator could be worked with.

The list would look like

```
English Spanish French
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=== EDIT ===

I misunderstood you question. Here is the corrected answer

====/EDIT ===

Assume name is the name of the language

```
var query = 
    from pair in 
    (from p in db.persons
    join l in db.personLanguages on p.personId equals l.personId
    select new {p, l})
group pair by pair.p into g
select new {Person = g.Key , Langs = string.Join(" " ,g.Select(gr=> gr.l.name).ToArray())}
```

Comment: How exactly does lang1, lang2 map to the appropiate field

Comment: It's because of the 'select l.name' part. (Assuming the language name column is called name). After that you have a series of just language names.

Comment: I didn't get that you want a pair of the person and languages, not only the languages. Sorry about that. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do A GroupBy first and then Join

```
var l = db.PersonLanguage.GroupBy(x => x.personId)
    .Select(x => new {gPersonId = x.Key, languages = x.Select(z=>z.LanguageId)})
    .Join(db.Person, a=> a.gPersonId, b=> b.personId, (a, b) => new {person = b, languages = a.languages});
```